# Cannot fork on Github

Tags: github

Hej,

I have a repository on the Github but I am unable to fork the repository. When I press the fork button nothing happen.

Any help would be appreciated

MVH
Adl

Comment: Did you already contacted Github support ?

Comment: I have not contacted Github support yet. I thought at the first place that I was doing wrong. Are you sure is it something to do with Githhub?